# Prononciation "bonshommes"

Tags: grammaire, prononciation

Comment doit-on prononcer le mot « ***bonshommes*** ? »

Est-ce qu'il doit se dire *bonZhomme* (comme dans *zèbre*)

Ou alors *bonShomme* (comme dans *serpent*) ?

Et pourquoi une grammaire particulière sur ce mot ?

Pourquoi y a-t-il un **double pluriel** ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On dit bonZhomme (comme dans zèbre).

Il n'y a pas de grammaire particulière, c'est juste un adjectif+nom devenu nom commun ce qui explique aussi l’orthographe: l'adjectif et le nom sont au pluriel comme dans 'de grands hommes'.

Comment: @jlliagre, merci d'avoir corrigé cette faute de frappe (il est assez ironique que la faute porte sur ce mot ;))

Comment: Oui, c'est classique :-)  On voit souvent plus facilement les coquilles des autres que les siennes.

Comment: D'ailleurs, on dit aussi [grandZhommes]. Et puis aussi dans la même veine, [deZhommes] et [uNhomme] : le 'h' est muet ; c'est pas comme la /fin des 'Zharicots/ et des 'Zhérissons écrasés, erreurs tellement communes, qu'on finit par ne plus s'en soucier.

Answer (score 19):

***Bonhomme*** a une grammaire particulière car formé par agglutination d'un adjectif et un nom commun. Contrairement à ***bonheur*** qui suit le même schéma (bon + heur=chance, destin), le nom commun ***bonhomme*** prend normalement la marque du pluriel pour ses deux composants (mais pas les *<s>bonsheurs</s>*). On retrouve le même schéma avec *un **gentil**homme* / *des **gentils**hommes* et les paires possessif + nom commun : ***mon**sieur* / ***mes**sieurs*, ***ma**dame* / ***mes**dames*, ***ma**demoiselle* / ***mes**demoiselles*, ***mon**seigneur* / ***mes**seigneurs*, etc.

Sa prononciation évolue et cette liaison se fait de nos jours de moins en moins entendre. J'entends par exemple toujours prononcer le pluriel *des **« bonnommes »** de neige* souvent d'ailleurs écrits *des **bonhommes** de neige* au lieu de ***bonshommes** de neige*. La même tendance se produit avec des **gentilshommes** où la liaison avec *S* est rarement réalisée aujourd'hui.

D'autre part, les dictionnaires indiquent que ce *S* intérieur n'apparaît pas au pluriel quand ***bonhomme*** est un adjectif.

Enfin, dans une liaison, on ne prononce jamais un *S* marquant le pluriel autrement que comme un *Z*, la deuxième prononciation de la question (bonShomme) est donc impossible.

Comment: Si je ne me trompe pas, le forme que vous décrivez comme « sans liaison » montre bien la liaison, mais c'est la liaison avec /n/ au lieu de celle avec /z/. (On ne dit pas \*/bɔ̃ɔm/, mais /bɔnɔm/.)

Comment: @ruakh Remarque pertinente. Cette liaison est aussi la prononciation attendue du singulier.

Answer (score 5):

Généralement, un mot comme *bonhomme* où « les deux éléments varient au pluriel phonétiquement et graphiquement » constitue une exception à l'idée que « les composés dont les éléments sont soudés dans l'écriture forment leur pluriel comme les noms ordinaires » (LBU14 § 533).

On prononce *bonshommes* [bɔ̃zɔm], *bon-zom* ; au Québec, à tout le moins, on trouve aussi le pluriel *bonhommes* prononcé [bɔnɔm], *bo-nom* ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1100)) comme quand on parle de [*bonhommes de neige*](https://montreal.ca/articles/concours-bonhommes-de-neige-9632)... On le qualifie de « populaire ou très familier » (LBU14 § 533 R1) ; « le pluriel enfantin *des bonhommes* s'est répandu au 20e sièce » (DHLF/Rey) ;  « on le rencontre pourtant chez les meilleurs auteurs » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bonhomme)).

Comment: Des bonz'hommes de neige là: https://www.facebook.com/watch/live/?v=1120404134990641&ref=watch_permalink

Comment: Oui, il y a de gens en France aussi, qui disent *les bonhommes* (notamment les enfants), et à vrai dire je ne crois pas quelqu'un dirait non plus "on va faire des bonshommes de neige", ça sonnerait un peu ridicule.

Comment: «Bonshommes» me semble diminuer considérablement la taille et l'importance du sujet. Des bonshommes animés, oui, mais jamais des bonshommes de neiges, sauf s'ils ne sont pas plus haut que trois pommes.

Answer (score 2):

L'Académie Française a rédigé un article sur ce sujet :

https://www.academie-francaise.fr/des-bonshommes-bien-bonhommes

> On acceptera cependant les formes bonshommes de neige et bonhommes de
> neige, en sachant que la première est de meilleure langue.

Ils indiquent que la prononciation du pluriel est "bon-z-hommes".

Answer (score 0):

In bons hommes, the adjective is plural because it agrees with the plural noun. Writing the words as a unit, bonshommes, doesn't change that.

Liaison is sometimes mandatory, sometimes forbidden, and sometimes optional. In this situation, with an adjective before a noun, it's mandatory.

The "s" is pronounced as Z here because it's before a vowel.

People vary in their use of liaison. Using it a lot in optional cases is a mark of educated people, who are showing that they know a word is written with a certain consonant on the end, even if the consonant may normally be silent.

Answer (score 0):

on ne prononce pas le "S", on prononce le nom normal comme étant au singulier. Mais pour distinguer entre le pluriel et le singulier c'est par l'écriture.

Comment: Aurais-tu des sources pour étayer ? Personnellement je prononce le "s" et la majorité de mes connaissances également.